# Refresh screen after Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I make a call to my controller, after a drop down is changed, which should return a new set of data for the screen, and refresh the screen.

```
function refresh() {
        var orderId = $(".cmbFilter").val();
        var accountId = $(".accountId").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Transactions", "Transaction")',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ bankAccountId: accountId, filterId: orderId }),
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {

                if (result.Success == 'true') {

                } else {
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Oh no...");
            }

        });
        return (false);
```

The call is made, the breakpoint in the controller is hit... but after the new model is returned - the screen doesn't refresh. How do I make the screen refresh?

I guess a simpler way would be something like this:

```
function refresh() {
    var orderId = $(".cmbFilter").val();
    var accountId = $(".accountId").val();
     window.location = '@Url.Action("Transactions", "Transaction", new {bankAccountId = orderId, filterId = accountId })';
}
```

However, it doesn't like my parameters (even when I use orderBy and accountId). What's wrong with the last attempt?

Says "It can't find symbol orderId and accountId"

Comment: When making an Ajax request the screen doesn't refresh (which is a good thing), if you want to update the view you have to update the DOM inside the ajax success handler. If you don't want to do that, you can always not use ajax and do a full page refresh.

Comment: I have a Table in my view that has to be refreshed based on the call.. For this, I guess I need to do a full refresh of the view then?

Comment: orderId, accountId  are client side javascript variables, @Url.Action is server side code, obviously server side code cannot access client side variables. In you case you have to generate the url and querystring on client side.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in your situation:

1. Put the html table in a partial view.
2. Create a controller action to retrieve data for it, return it, etc.
3. Put a div (id="myDiv") on your main view, with RenderAction("MyNewAction") inside it to get the initial load of the table/partial view
4. On some action, make your ajax call to the new action (note the content type change)
5. "Re-populate" the table with the result of the call to your new action:

   contentType: "html",
   success: function (result) {
       $("#myDiv").html(result);
       }

Answer (score 0):

```
if (result.Success == 'true') 
{
    // refresh your drop down here
} 
else 
{
    // do you really want to hide and ignore error messages?
}
```

Comment: In my view, I have a table built based on values in a List<> in my model. This list refreshes, so I need to refresh the table. Can I do that from within this query? Or do I need to do a full page reload?

Comment: But javascript/jquery doesn't know anything about List<>.  You have sent the data in the JSON format, it is up to the client to put the returned data into the DOM.

Comment: OK, I edited my question. Can you spot the issue with my second attempt?

Comment: You have sent data to the server.   The server has responded with data which you are ignoring.   You can either do something with the data returned by the Ajax call, or do a full submit to the server, it will rebuild everything and the page will reload.  Of course, that defeats the purpose of using an AJAX call...avoiding reloads.

Comment: Your second attempt....you are getting the OLD values from the screen.  But it doesn't matter because you are not passing them to the window.location change.